# Convert mySQL Query to QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

i have a query like this:

```
SELECT a.id

FROM  Tabel a

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id
    FROM  Tabel AS alt
    WHERE  alt.first = 1
    OR  alt.second = 1
    GROUP BY  least(second ,  first), greatest(second ,  first)
)b ON a.id = b.id
```

and i want convert this to 'createQueryBuilder' format.

I have really no any idea, how can i do `INNER JOIN () ON`.
Any advice ?
Thanks !